# The set of all cycles of length 3 are a conjugancy class of $A_5$

Tags: group-theory

Because permutations are conjugate iff they have the same cyclic structure, this is true in $S_5$. But now I'm stuck on trying to prove that there exists an $\sigma \in A_5$ for all $(abc), (def)$ such that $\sigma(abc)\sigma^{-1} = (def)$. I've tried a few examples, but there was no obvious pattern (for example (24)(35)(123)(24)(35) = (145) and (45)(123)(45) = (123)). Also $\sigma(abc)\sigma^{-1} = (\sigma(a)\sigma(b)\sigma(c))$. And $\sigma = \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c & z & x \\
d & e & f & h & k \end{pmatrix}$ is an conjugator for $(abc)$ and $(def)$

So if someone could give a hint, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that a conjugacy class in $S_n$ consisting of even
permutations remains a conjugacy class in $A_n$, all one needs
is that there is an odd permutation commuting with one element of
the class. Here $(4\,5)$ is odd and commutes with $(1\,2\,3)$.

Comment: The reason for this is that if you have an odd permutation which sends your original cycle to another, you can conjugate first by the transposition (or other odd permutation) without changing the result (conjugation has no effect if elements commute), and that enables you to get the same result with an even permutation - i.e. within the alternating group.